# I want to access the ForeignKey and bring querysets in django-admin

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to access the ForeignKey and bring querysets. Below pic is that I approached the instance and brought only the object. But I want to bring a query set.

`def card_income (self, instance):` how can I get this part into querysets, not object?

This function is an object, so obj.It can be approached like `obj.account_amount`. But I want to bring querysets.

```
#admin.py
@admin.register(DailySettlement)
class DailySettlementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "card_income",

    )
    list_filter = (('accountbook', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter), 
    )


    def card_income(self, instance):
        obj=instance.accountbook

        print("000", obj)
        package_amount=obj.account_amount
        print("111", package_amount)
        return package_amount
    
    card_income.short_description = '카드 수익'
```

```
# models.py

class AccountBook(TimeStampedModel):
    account_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], null=False, verbose_name="금액")

class DailySettlement(models.Model):
    accountbook = models.ForeignKey(AccountBook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, verbose_name="회계정산 외래키")
    settlement_card_income = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="일일정산 카드 수익")
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from calling `AccountBook.objects.{Whatever}` inside card_income.

Comment: you are genious! thx @misraX